# Switch between fragments in android?

Tags: android, fragment, sliding

I want to switch from one `fragment` to another such that my `PreviousFragment` doesn't close fully and my `NewFragment` doesn't fit the whole screen width but `100 dp` short and the `NewFragment` comes sliding over the another. Is this possible with the use of animation ? Please provide some link. I am a beginner with fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is a LayoutTransition. It handles all animation for transitions between fragment changes. when you use replace and are using a layout transition on the main view which contains the fragment then you will have this animation.